# Speech bubble type option view on clicking ImageView?

Tags: android, android-view, android-dialog

I have seen this type of view somewhere but I don't remember.When you click on an item speech bubble type option menu will appear.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is right what I understood, what I understood from your question is that when you click on the imageview a bubble appears ?

I think you should make `onClickListener` for your **imageview** and when it's clicked a dialogue appears by `.show()`

first your create the dialogue and you can shape it whatever you want like a bubble (search the site), and imageview.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_clk);
            dialog.setTitle("click");

imageview i = (Imageview) findViewById(R.id.iView);
```

then set the clicking listener

```
    i.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
//here you show the dialogue
dialogue.show();
                    }
            });
```

to remove the dialogue use

```
dialog.dismiss();
```